# Collapsible inside a controlgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a data-role "controlgroup" inside a "collapsible". The problem is that I need to make the control group selection unique, only one checked for each selection. At this moment when I select an option it stays selected and doesn't even unselect when clicked again.

here is the code:

```
   <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Food type list</h4>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2a" id="Vegetariano1" value="off">
                <label for="Vegetariano1">Vegetarian</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2b" id="Dieta1" value="off">
                <label for="Dieta1">Diet</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2c" id="Consumo_diario1" value="on" checked="checked">
                <label for="Consumo_diario1">Varied consumption</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <p></p>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Health condition list</h4>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="false">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-3a" id="Diabetico1" value="off">
                <label for="Diabetico1">Diabetic</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-3b" id="Cardiaco1" value="off">
                <label for="Cardiaco1">Cardiac</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-3c" id="Hipertenso1" value="off">
                <label for="Hipertenso1">Hypertensive</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-3d" id="Saudavel1" value="on" checked="checked">
                <label for="Saudavel1">Healthy</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

JSFiddle link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/xnon711o/)

Answer (score 0):

`name` attribute for each group should be the same.

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="Diabetico1" value="off">
<label for="Diabetico1">Diabetic</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="Cardiaco1" value="off">
<label for="Cardiaco1">Cardiac</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="Hipertenso1" value="off">
<label for="Hipertenso1">Hypertensive</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="Saudavel1" value="on" checked="checked">
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ega8m1zn/)**